# Is there any analog to property binding via fxml in JavaFX?

Tags: xaml, binding, javafx, fxml

In JavaFX [property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html) can be bound to some [observable value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ObservableValue.html).

```
Label l = new Label();
l.visibleProperty().bind(l.textProperty().length().isEqualTo(3));

l.setText("123");  // show label
l.setText("1234"); // hide label
```

Recently I have discovered that binding can be done not only in code but in FXML markup document.

```
<!-- Label is visible only if input is visible. -->
<Label l="Please input some value:" visible="${value.visible}" />
<TextField fx:id="value" />
```

Is there similar feature in another languages and markup tools or that is kind of oracle innovation? :-)

update: I added XAML tag because I guess it has something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that QML has the [same feature](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html).